# How to find the executed file name and type

Tags: android, operating-system, filesystems

In android phone we execute a file using different application like video player, audio player, pdf reader etc.
How can I get the file name and type for a file which is just executed from an application this way?
When we open a file in Windows Explorer, the name of the file is recorded by the operating system.  Some of the names are saved into the 'Recent' folder.
Is there in android any similar option, which can provide me the executed file name?

Comment: did you found my answer helpful!!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the file type either using file extension or using below method

```
ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
```